# Mastering SAS programming

Tags: sas

Learning SAS

I am new to SAS, have completed SAS base programming essential from SAS and Second part from Coursera "Doing more with SAS". Now I need to practice, please guide me, if there are more course shoudl i take or how to practice to learn more.

Comment: I would recommend taking advanced programming from SAS.

Comment: Answer questions on communities.sas.com for learning, do projects on kaggle/datadriven using SAS that you can include in a portfolio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked best for me was reading through articles from the https://www.lexjansen.com/, it is on-line library of SAS articles from various local and international conferences. Those papers contains a lot of practical ideas and solutions to everyday SAS programme problems, including those with "advance" label.

One additional "worth reading" is this article with set of "golden rules" for SAS programmers: [Maxims of Maximally Efficient SAS Programmers](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Maxims-of-Maximally-Efficient-SAS-Programmers/ta-p/352068). It is a list of guidelines, a.k.a. "good SAS programming practices", which make your experience with the tool better. Good reading both for "rookies" and for "seasoned" SASers.

Good place to "polish" your SAS skills and general knowledge is this online quiz: [sasensei](https://sasensei.com)